# Swift: Firebase Storage Code Block Not Executing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I have the following function to pull images from a Firebase Storage database.

For some reason, the print(imageRef) line is working well but the imageRef.getData() code block is being skipped completely. It's not executing either of the print statements "error updating..." or "Got the image".

What could be causing this?

```
    func updateCurrentUser() {

        var downloadedImages : [UIImage?] = []

        for i in 0...8 {
            let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference()

            let imageRef = storageRef.child(self.currentUser.userid + "/img" + String(i) + ".jpg")
            print(imageRef)

            // Download in memory with a maximum allowed size of 1MB (1 * 1024 * 1024 bytes)
            imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
                if let error = error {
                    print("error updating returning user: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                } else {
                    // Data for the image is returned
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    downloadedImages[i] = image
                    print("Got the image")
                }
            }
        }

        self.currentUser.images = downloadedImages
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is asynchronous and firebase data is only valid within the closure following the firebase function. In a nutshell, code is faster than the internet and it takes time for data to download.

Here's an abbreviated version of your code... note the comments

```
func updateCurrentUser() {
    var downloadedImages : [UIImage?] = []
    for i in 0...8 {
        imageRef.getData(maxSize: 1 * 1024 * 1024) { data, error in
           //firebase data is ONLY valid here so append each image to an array
           self.currentUser.images.append(downloadedImage)
        }
    }

    //the following line will execute WAY before the images are downloaded
    //   so self.currentUser.images will always be empty
    self.currentUser.images = downloadedImages
}
```

You're probably going to want to use a completion handler as well. See my answer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203762/retrieve-an-image-from-firebase-to-an-uiimage-swift5/60212828#60212828) for further reading