# Can anyone help me with this issue of retrieving data from Firebase using swift on Xcode? "Editor placeholder in source file"

Tags: swift, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So basically I have been having an issue with an error that keeps popping up in my code when I try to get documents from Firestore. Im not really sure why, can someone please clarify it to me. I am trying to use the structure of Log and to capture the different fields in a document. After this, I want add it to an array of Logs so that I can then present in my view.

My code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
```

This is the Log structure which I wanted to use to model my data:

```
struct Log {

// MARK: - Properties


var date : Date

var leftUO  : Bool
var leftUI  : Bool
var leftLI  : Bool
var leftLO  : Bool

var rightUO : Bool
var rightUI : Bool
var rightLI : Bool
var rightLO : Bool


 }
```

And this is the way I wanted to retrieve the data from firebase and store it locally.

```
struct LogsModel {
    let storage = Firestore.firestore()
    func retrieveLogs(uid: String, user : String) -> [Log] {
        var logs : [Log] = []
        storage.collection("/LOGS" + user + uid).getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        
            guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else {
                print(error?.localizedDescription  ?? "Documents not retrived")
                return
            }
            
            for document in documents {
                let date     = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.DATE)
                let fieldLLI = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTLOWERINNER)
                let fieldLLO = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTLOWEROUTER)
                let fieldLUO = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTLOWEROUTER)
                let fieldLUI = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.LEFTUPPERINNER)
                let fieldRLI = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTLOWERINNER)
                let fieldRLO = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTLOWEROUTER)
                let fieldRUO = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTUPPEROUTER)
                let fieldRUI = document.get(Constants.FirebaseConstants.RIGHTUPPERINNER)
                
                let log = Log(date: date as! Date,
                              leftUO: fieldLUO as! Bool,
                              leftUI: fieldLUI as! Bool,
                              leftLI: fieldLLI as! Bool,
                              leftLO: fieldLLO as! Bool,
                              rightUO: fieldRUO as! Bool,
                              rightUI: fieldRUI as! Bool,
                              rightLI: fieldRLI as! Bool,
                              rightLO: fieldRLO as! Bool)
                // TODO - extract document into Log struct and add that to logs array
                logs += [log]
            }
        }
        return logs
    }
}
```

I hope I clarified my issue enough. Thanks in advance for your help I really appreciate it

Comment: “Editor placeholder in source file” means there is a placeholder somewhere. That's the gray rectangle thing. You need to replace that with an actual variable or something.

Comment: The comment from @aheze is correct. But, you've got another issue; `return logs` statement falls outside the Firebase closure so it will actually execute before the code inside the closure, almost always returning nil - firebase closures cannot return data in that way. Firebase is asynchronous See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60203762/retrieve-an-image-from-firebase-to-an-uiimage-swift5/60212828#60212828) or maybe [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272535/i-keep-getting-a-sigabrt-error-when-trying-to-read-my-firebase-database-and-crea/60383635#60383635)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting this as a community wiki since it's based on @Aheze's comments:

The error that you are getting `Editor placeholder in source file`, means that there is a placeholder somewhere in your code, which will be indicated by a grey or blue block and will need to be replaced by something of that value.

[Here is an example of a placeholder in the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZo4c.png)

Also, make sure to do a project clean before running it again as this can also be getting triggered by Xcode for no reason at all.

Comment: Thank you!!! I feel embarrassed that its a quick fix but thanks for pointing it out to me.